# Zepto support for data-* attributes through .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, zepto

I'm using [Zepto.js](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto), a lightweight jquery clone. But that framework doesn't use .data() in the same way as jquery. Now I need to use this code:

```
var position = new Array;
$('#ipadmenu > section').each(function() {
    position.push($(this).data('order'));
});
```

But I have no idea how to make this work on my framework.
How would I convert this to pure javascript? I have never really worked with arrays so i'm quite lost... also, might I have skipped something in the zepto doc (https://github.com/madrobby/zepto) that could help me with this? .get() for example?

Here is the HTML code. Basically I want to add all sections (the amount can change) into the array:

```
<nav id="ipadmenu">
    <section data-order="0">
        <a><p>text</p></a>
    </section>
    <section data-order="1">
        <a><p>text</p></a>
    </section>
</nav>
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: Slight nitpick... jQuery _is_ "real JavaScript."

Comment: `.push` will have little to do with the framework since you're calling it on an array.

Comment: jQuery is just pre-written libraries of JavaScript code..

Comment: yes true, I changed it to "pure" :p

Comment: @pimvdb is .push a regular javascript function then?

Comment: I googled it and yes I guess it is :)

Comment: Need to use a standard JS selector like dom.getElementById()

Comment: Please post an example of the HTML `<section>`

Comment: -1 and vote to close for grossly inept title and question.

Comment: Where does the data in `order` come from and what are you going to do with it are info we will need to answer.

Comment: You know, I have never used zepto before, but perusing it's docs, it appears to support all the jQuery methods you are using. So what, specfifically, is not working in your code example?

Comment: That code snippet doesn't execute but I think it might come from somewhere else then. I think I missunderstood the docs... I'll try to look for a bug somewhere else :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my 30 second review of the zepto docs, it would look like this.

```
var position = new Array;
$('#ipadmenu > section').each(function() {
    position.push($(this).data('order'));
});
```

the zepto docs you linked to say it supports all of the jquery methods in your snippet.

What about the data doesn't it handle? If it really doesn't handle `data` the same it also supports `attr` so you could say:

```
var position = new Array;
$('#ipadmenu > section').each(function() {
    position.push($(this).attr('data-order'));
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Doe sit support data? I don't know i'm confused, not very good at javascript. Tried to read both documentations and they said different tings, and my code doesn't execute. I think i made another mistake then. Thank you for helping, i will try the attr too :).

Answer (score 1):

Here an alternative "pure" javascript solution:

```
var position = [];
var aSections = document.getElementById('ipadmenu').childNodes;
for (iIndex in aSections) {
    if (aSections[iIndex].nodeName == 'SECTION') {
        position.push(aSections[iIndex].getAttribute('data-order'));
    }
}
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UXbpq/).

=== UPDATE ===

A little smaler solution:

```
var position = [];
var aSections = document.getElementById('ipadmenu').getElementsByTagName('SECTION');
for (i = 0; i < aSections.length; i++) {
    position.push(aSections[i].getAttribute('data-order'));
}
```

Here the new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QAMcw/).

Comment: lovely! it is always better to use "pure" javascript in my oppinion! for speed of course! so thank you for your work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the data-* attributes then you can access them through the new [dataset](http://eligrey.com/blog/post/html-5-dataset-support) object available in HTMLElement. dataset is a StringMap object so you access the values using camel cased attribute names as the keys. If dataset is not available (if browser isn't HTML5 compatible or dataset spec is not implemented in the browser) then you can access the attribute using the regular attribute retrieval method.

So, if you have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataSet = document.getElementById("input1").dataset;
for(var key in dataSet) {
    console.log("attribute is: " + key);
    console.log(dataSet[key]);
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="input1" data-custom-attribute="some value"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Zepto support $(elem).data("attr-name") method, when you use a Custom Build of Zepto with ["data"](http://zeptojs.com/#download) module. So, you can use same code for jquery and Zepto